# Sharepoint 2007 Custom permission level to manage permissions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, permissions

I have a problem: I need to add custom permission level to sharepoint, that grants access to manage permissions and view (read only) pages.

The permission levels that I set to the permission level are:

```
                    SPBasePermissions.Open
                                | SPBasePermissions.ApproveItems
                                | SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems
                                | SPBasePermissions.OpenItems
                                | SPBasePermissions.ViewVersions
                                | SPBasePermissions.ViewPages
                                | SPBasePermissions.BrowseDirectories
                                | SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions
                                | SPBasePermissions.BrowseUserInfo
                                | SPBasePermissions.CreateGroups
                                | SPBasePermissions.ViewFormPages
                                | SPBasePermissions.ManagePermissions;
```

I can Add Groups but "Add user" is unvisible. What I am missing here?

thx!

Answer (score 0):

also include `SPBasePermissions.ManageLists`

Comment: Didnt help, I figured out that I need to be a owner of a groups that I want this group to manage. Thats not whot I am looking for cause there is something like hundreds of groups. Is there any work-a-round solution for this?